# Associate Arrays with PHP code

Tags: php, arrays

I am learning php and having trouble understanding how to use an associate arrays with user inputs. I will eventually need to sort my array by a key value but for now I just dont know if I am doing it correctly. The examples in the book didn't show how to get a user input and use it in an array just predetermine values. Can someone please help me and tell me if I on the right track. I understand I need to use the $_POST method to get the information for the array but I just cant figure out how to use it. When i upload what i have i keep getting error

```
    <HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Student Form</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<FORM METHOD="post" ACTION="final_project.php">
<P>Please enter your name: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="txtname" SIZE= 10></P>
<P>Please enter your id: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="txtid" SIZE= 10></P>
<P>Please enter your address: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="txtaddress" SIZE= 10></P>
<P>Please enter your cell phone number: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="txtcell" SIZE= 10></P>
<P>Please enter your Major: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="txtmajor" SIZE= 10></P>
<P>Please enter your E-mail address: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="txtemail" SIZE= 10></P>
<P><INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="submit" VALUE="Submit"></P>
</FORM>
<?php
$txtname = $_POST['txtname'];
$txtid = $_POST['txtid'];
$txtaddress = $_POST['txtaddress'];
$txtcell = $_POST['txtcell'];

$array = array(txtname=>$txtname, txtid=>$txtid, txtaddress=>$txtaddress,
txtcell=>$txtcell);

for each ($txtid as $key => $array){
echo "Your first name is ".$txtname.", id number is ".$txtid[$key].", your address is
".$txtaddress.", phone number is ".$txtcell.".";

}
?>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

NEW UPDATE: 
    $txtname[0] = $_POST['txtname'];
    $txtid[1] = $_POST['txtid'];
    $txtaddress[2] = $_POST['txtaddress'];
    $txtcell[3] = $_POST['txtcell'];
    $txtmajor[4] = $_POST['txtmajor'];
    $txtemail[5] = $_POST['txtemail'];

```
$student = array('txtname'=>$txtname, 'txtid'=>$txtid, 'txtaddress'=>$txtaddress,
'txtcell'=>$txtcell, 'txtmajor'=>$txtmajor, 'txtemail'=>$txtemail);

foreach ($student as $key => $txtname){
print_r ($student[$key]);
}
```

Array ( [0] => Amanda ) Array ( [1] => 12 ) Array ( [2] => 123 West Main Street ) Array ( [3] => 888-888-8888 ) Array ( [4] => CIS ) Array ( [5] => email@email.com )

I have updated the code. I cant get it to print out my array correctly.

I want it to be = Array( [0] => Amanda) [1]=>12 [2]=> 123 west main street...) what am i doing wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting?  You might want to edit your question to describe the error instead of putting it in a comment.

Comment: your array declaration is missing some quotes

Comment: Although not the answer to your question, perhaps this will help you find the answer: http://bbrown.spsu.edu/papers/php2.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Form \_POST array problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923563/form-post-array-problem)

Comment: `foreach` is the correct keyword, not `for each`.

Comment: Turn error reporting all the way up and display errors on screen. PHP will be complaining about undefined constants in that array declaration.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` _always_ when developing code.

Comment: You're not checking to see if the form has been submitted so when you run this the form will be displayed and the PHP code will be executed immediately before the `$_POST` array has been populated. Take a look at the PHP reference on [Form Handling](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'each' (T_STRING), expecting '(' in /home/masters/www/final_project.php on line 22

This is the error I was getting but I didnt know if I was doing the array right to even start debugging the error. 

I just get confused because I am drawing my array values from variables and not know words like in the examples I saw online.

Answer (score 1):

The [PHP manual for "foreach"](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) says to do it like this:

```
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
```

But you have it like this:

```
for each ($txtid as $key => $array){ ... }
```

My guess is you want to replace that whole part with this:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $txtid ) {
  echo "your $key is $txtid ";
}
```

Comment: It's impossible to debug your code in the comments; did u try what i suggested?  Start with what you had in your question, just replace your "for each" section with mine.

Comment: Replaced the foreach loop and it seems to work. I have to change it around a bit. I was just lost before on when I had to reword it but since i put it in an see how it works I understand now. 

Thank you again for you help. Arrays just always confuse me.

Comment: Ok i am now stuck on how to get my array to print correctly. I have it now so it keeps prints each individual input as an array and that is in correct.

Comment: you'd have to post your code, maybe update your question or post a new question if you have substantial changes.

Comment: i see, not sure your intent but i think you just want to change `print_r ($student[$key]);` to `print $student[$key];` (took away the _r after "print")

Comment: the print_r is use to print arrays. or at least that is what my book told me. I tried without the "_r" and nothing showed up on my screen.

Comment: you're using a function to print arrays on the individual elements and the output looks like what you should expect in that case - each array in the output has only one single element.  maybe you want `print_r ($student);` without the foreach and $key.

Comment: I tried just ($student); that printed the same thing 6 times
I have 6 lines listing all my my input values and there indexes. 
I tried not using the for each and just using for. nothing made it work. it went backwards, showing just " ". I understand what your saying about me printing only a single element instead of the whole list. I was able to sort my array even if says array after ever item.

Comment: yeah you are looping over each element and printing the whole array for each element.  just leave out the foreach and use `print_r($student);`  If you are really going to learn arrays I advise you to spend more time experimenting with this until you understand the basic array functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not neccessary to to an array to get informations, you can just do like this :

```
<?php

// your form

$txtname = $_POST['txtname'];
$txtid = $_POST['txtid'];
$txtaddress = $_POST['txtaddress'];
$txtcell = $_POST['txtcell'];


echo "Your first name is ".$txtname.", id number is ".$txtid[$key].", your address is
".$txtaddress.", phone number is ".$txtcell.".";
```

?>

Comment: I would love not to use an array but we require one for the project.